# Use sendgrid from multiple domains without whitelabel

Tags: email, sendgrid, white-labelling

I'm trying to understand a few concepts around sendgrid, whitelabeling and different servers that I plan to deploy the same sendgrid account in.

So my questions are:

1) Is whitelabelling purely for masking the via sendgrid.me and will I have any issues if I dont use it with my current setup(i.e. same account on several domains)

2) How does sendgrid deal with messages that have a "From" email that doesnt match the domain the email is sent from? Cause I read that it would silently drop them but instead I see that emails do get delivered however the statistics in sendgrid's dashboard are not being updated.

3) Upon creating a demo account I was asked to provide the domain from which the emails will be triggered but since I want to deploy this in several different domains will I need multiple accounts or is there an alternative option when you go for a paid plan?

Mike

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Yes - whitelabelling will replace the sendgrid.me with your own domain.

You can also setup multiple domains inside SendGrid and assign each to a subuser. That will get you one SendGrid account, with multiple whitelabelled domains and separate sender reputation for each.

2. SendGrid will attempt delivery of whatever you ask it to send -- if you send an email with a different from domain than the signed sending domain, it's up to the receiving mail server to decide whether to block, flag as spam, or allow the email. Different receiving domains will behave differently.

It's generally best practice to always have your from domain match your signed sender domain.

3. Once you have one domain setup, you can setup additional domains using SendGrid subusers -- [more info here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/subusers).

If you have a complicated multi-domain setup, you might want to check out a templating API, like [sendwithus](https://www.sendwithus.com/), for making things easier to manage. They'll integrate directly with your SendGrid subusers on your behalf.